# I'm not sure what printf("%lld\n",ans); means

Tags: c++

I couldn't find anything online about what the \n does. I removed it to see what happened and I got a compilation error.
Thanks!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Answer (score 1):

Actually `\n` means to print a **new line** in the console. And the compilation error was due to a missing slash before `\n`. Because in c `\` is a **special char**. so we need to escape that char by adding one more slash before that.

Try this:

```
printf("%lld\\n",ans);
```

`%lld or %lli` means Signed Integer and supported data type(`long long`). So the type of `ans` variable has to be `long long` I guess.

Reference:
https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: “\\n” prints a backslash followed by the letter `n`. There is nothing in the question that indicates that that’s the desired result. You don’t know what caused the error because you haven’t seen the modified code.